# Parsing Array Post Form Data in Go

Tags: html, forms, post, go

So I have this form:

```
<form method="POST" action="/parse">
    <div>   
        <input name="photo[0]" value="Hey I'm photo zero!" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="photo[1]" value="Photo one here!" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="photo[2]" value="Awh I'm photo 2 but I'm the third photo..." />
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

In Go, it appears, the `net/http` library will allow you to query the form data one at a time by string key in the form:

```
r.PostFormValue("photo[0]")
```

Is there an easy way to parse this form directly as a slice in Go?

That is, being able to access the elements of photo like this:

```
photos := r.PostFormValue("photo");
log.Println(photos[1]);
```

Or any other suggestion on properly accessing 'array like' data structures in form post data in Golang aside from string munging...

Comment: Why the PHP tag here ? This makes the question really unclear. And what's the "this" you want to "accomplish" ?

Comment: @BlinkyTop what are you asking?

Comment: Hope that edit clarifies the question.  Moving to Go from PHP and trying to get the parallels figured out.

Answer (score 4):

Don’t add array index in name, use same name for all inputs. 
The http library will parse field with the same name to a slice.

```
<form method="POST" action="/parse">
    <div>   
        <input name="photo" value="Hey I'm photo zero!" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="photo" value="Photo one here!" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="photo" value="Awh I'm photo 2 but I'm the third photo..." />
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What IF i have something like Contact[Name], Contact[Email], Contact[Message] in my html form ?

Comment: @DavidLavieri if it's only one object, just use <input name="Name"> <input name="Email"> etc.

Comment: Thanks, but I pass through scenarios where i need to divide the data  (many objects) really often, you can check this, Where I explain it better http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34839811/how-to-retrieve-form-data-as-array-in-golang

Comment: Question asked how to handle the request in Go, not how to write an html. JS FormData supports sending arrays and objects as well, so the expected answer would be how to handle those data in the backend.